# Drag mouse events jittery - onmousemove

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, video, youtube

Working on a scrub bar for a chromeless player through youtube.  I have the functionality working pretty much as Id like BUT when I click to drag the blue "seeker" button and drag it, it jumps back to its original position *until* I release the mouse click.  Once I release, it starts the video at the appropriate position and draws the progress bar at the appropriate position too.  code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/VysBU/1/

I also logged the position of the mouse and width of the progress bar (which is the part that jumps around) and the width values move consistently upward or downward on drag which doesn't make sense because visually, it jumps back and forth.  Odd.

Any help is appreciated...if you need me to clarify something, let me know.

NOTE: just remembered...it tends to jump on vertical mouse movements only.  ie, if i move the mouse horizontally without changing its vertical position at all, it 'animates' fine.  if the vertical position does move, the 'animations' are erratic.

Comment: Can't find the problem but just to make you aware that there is the official jQuery UI slider here http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/. It will save you a lot of trouble trying to get it to work across browsers, so use that unless you have a specific reason not to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out http://jsfiddle.net/sz4FF/

you need to stop the interval of

```
setInterval(animateProgress, 100);
```

when you begin seeking, and continue it when the seeking stops. The reason why it makes that jump is simply because animateProgress is called and sets the width of the playedBar and seeker.

I hastily added it to a global function (window.TEST_INTERVAL) just to check if it would work, and it does.

(how to initialize and clear the interval)

```
clearInterval(TEST_INTERVAL);
TEST_INTERVAL = setInterval(animateProgress, 100);
```

within seeking

```
function seeking(e){
        clearInterval(TEST_INTERVAL);
```

within doneSeeking

```
function doneSeeking(e){
         TEST_INTERVAL = setInterval(animateBuffer, 250);
```

UPDATE: IE8 and below problem

```
    mousePos  = e==undefined ? event.clientX : e.pageX;
    //get the position of the mouse
    //mousePos = e.pageX;
```

the event returned by onmousemove is "undefined" in ie7 and 8, that way we are checking for window.event.clientX, which shows the mouse position relative to the window.  It seems to work fine but I believe that in a normal environment some minor tweaks might be needed

Comment: Awesome.  Thank you.  Actually, I literally just figured this out a few seconds ago doing it a different (and less elegant) way as well.  Basically, I added a boolean flag 'notSeeking' that is added to the if statement which controls the animation in animateProgress and set it to false in seeking() and true in doneSeeking().  It works but again, Pantelis' answer is better.  Thank you.

Comment: Another note about this, it does not work in IE.  Any ideas why?

Comment: Hey again. Check this one!!  http://jsfiddle.net/sz4FF/

(I will edit my above post)